# How to solve this err ionic-app-scripts: Permission denied

Tags: ionic3

we are using the ubuntu system
ionic info

```
Cordova CLI: 6.3.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 3.1.1
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.2
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.3.6
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Linux 4.4
Node Version: v6.0.0
Xcode version: Not installed
```

when I am  giving the ionic serve, I am getting this error

```
sh: 1: ionic-app-scripts: Permission denied

npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-72-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "ionic:serve" "--" "--v2" "--address" "0.0.0.0" "--port" "8101" "--livereload-port" "35730"
npm ERR! node v6.0.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! ionic-hello-world@0.0.0 ionic:serve: `ionic-app-scripts serve "--v2" "--address" "0.0.0.0" "--port" "8101" "--livereload-port" "35730"`
```

Comment: we are  copy the project  ios to android

Comment: run it with sudo..
`sudo su`